# how to get exact string match for multiple string in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am new to ruby, I am using ruby regex for puppet host based declaration, I am trying to write a regex to match servers with either web or dev or soa at end of hostname but when i tried puppet dry run i came to know that my server atl-dum-db01 is also matched in this regex. below is the output of my problem

```
2.1.2 :123 > "^atl-dum-web01".match(/^atl-dum-[webdevsoa\d]+/)
 => #<MatchData "atl-dum-web01">
2.1.2 :124 > "^atl-dum-db01".match(/^atl-dum-[webdevsoa\d]+/)
 => #<MatchData "atl-dum-db01">
```

Could someone please help me, Sorry for my bad english

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of character class is wrong. Inside character class there are no groups and every character is matched individually.

You need to use this regex for your case:

```
/^atl-dum-(web|dev|soa)\d+$/
```